# Android Jitpack build library not working

Tags: android, jitpack

I have a library which includes transitive libraries inside. I want to include this library to another project with JitPack.

First of all I prepared my code according JitPack's docs https://jitpack.io/docs/BUILDING/ and https://jitpack.io/docs/PRIVATE/

Then I created a private repository and uploaded there my library. Created release and installed gradle.

Then I get gradle dependency from JitPack, but it built with error:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3m 16s
179 actionable tasks: 174 executed, 5 up-to-date
Build tool exit code: 0
Looking for artifacts...
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Looking for pom.xml in build directory and ~/.m2
Found artifact: https://github.com/ilyinp:app:1.0.4
2020-01-21T05:25:55.722858568Z
Exit code: 0

ERROR: No build artifacts found
Expected artifacts in: $HOME/.m2/repository//github.com/ilyinp/app
```

Also on my computer I have directory `$HOME/.m2/repository/https:/github/com/ilyinp/app/unspecified` which contains files: `app-unspecified.aar`, `app-unspecified.pom`, `app-unspecifed-javadoc.jar`, `app-unspecified-sources.jar`

File `app-unspecified.pom` contains info about all third-party libs and my own transitive libs.

How to make JitPack builds work?